# Change URL for when this form is processed

Tags: php, url, search, search-engine

I have a form that has no action attribute, a method of get, and a single input field of type text with a name of q.

When one enters 'query' and submits the form, the URL of the confirmation page looks like `http://mySite.com/search.php?q=query`.

How can I get the URL to be `http://mySite.com/search?q=query`

And for multi-word searches (like for 'query one') `http://mySite.com/search?q=query+one` ?

All while still navigating to the confirmation / results page.

How can I do this? I would prefer a solution not involving .htacess

Comment: Rewrite the url in your htaccess file.

Comment: @ManishJangir I can't use .htacess of this server. I tried all of this on a server that supported .htacess and all I was able to do was redirect to that URL. But the results page was never reached and the form never received any data for the results page to display.

Comment: @Irfan Mir Please edit in your post .. like you don't want solution in htaccess ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the following code in your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search\?q\=([^/]*)$ /search.php?q=$1 [L]
```

and then use http://mySite.com/search as action file in your form

Comment: Is there a way to do this without .htacess? Like with pure PHP. My current server doesn't support .htacess.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without .htaccess because you have to tell the server that the url you are using does exists.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do this is Rewrite htaccess file..
But you are telling u tried this

so this is pure php

In `$a` i have taken this string..
You have to get URL directly from the current page using PHP

```
   $a= 'http://mySite.com/search.php?q=query';
   echo $a;

   echo "</br>";
   $b= str_replace('.php','',$a);
   echo $b;
```

---

for space

```
   $a= 'http://mySite.com/search.php?q=query one';


   echo "</br>";
   $b= str_replace('.php','',$a);
   $c= str_replace(' ','+',$b);
   echo $c;
```

Not an efficient solution but it will work..

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible ways to solve this problem is to route your requests to one PHP-file (`index.php`) which script parses request's URL and choose appropriate action (in your case - search).

If you have Apache Web server, you can use [Rewrite Rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) in `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @IrfanMir No, the URL will be such as you wish. But every request will be redirected to `index.php` script.

Comment: I want the URLs to look like how I described above, but every request sent to search.php not index.php. how do I do that?

Comment: @IrfanMir So use Manish Jangir's answer

Comment: Okay, I will then. First, I have to wait before I can select an answer.

Answer (score -1):

For multiple terms simply do this:
`$query = str_replace(' ', '+', $_GET['search']);`

For the redirect you could check if $_GET is_empty() and then display another html-page accordingly:
`if (!is_empty($_GET)) echo file_get_contents('result.html');`
`else echo file_get_contents('form.html')`

A very basic way of doing it. You may need to add a few more checks though.